# What is the fastest way to extract a substring from a string, up to a delimiter in C#?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, optimization

So I'm parsing a large file and I need to optimize my string extraction process (it currently takes about 1-2 mins for the program to even finish parsing the file). Which is a killer for debugging and further developing the software.

Example program

```
string sample = "First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line";
string extracted_string = ExtractString(ref sample, "\n");
// extracted_string should hold "First Line"
// sample should hold "Second Line\nThird Line";
```

The ExtractString Function

```
function string ExtractString(ref string original, string delimiter)
{
    int index_of = original.IndexOf(delimiter);
    string result = "";

    if(index_of >= 0)
    {
       result = original.Substring(0, index_of);

       // Remove string & delimiter from original
       original = original.Remove(0, index_of + 1);
    }
    else
    {
       result = original;
       original = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is there a different way for me to do this to speed up the process.... So far each record is taking about 50-80ms to process and there are probably around 6000-7000 records.

Comment: have you tried string.split ?

Comment: Maybe consider using StringBuilder? Manipulating string in `StringBuilder` should much faster.

Comment: Do you really need to trim away the found string from the original string? If you don't need a trimmed original string then you could pass the index of the last found newline to use as starting point for the next substring clip or use a total different approach to work with your file

Comment: String builder won't work as I need to be able to search the string.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [string.Split(char delimeter)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It's much faster than your operations on strings. String is unmutable and this characteristic generate your performance problems. In each operation new memory is allocated. Change your method to:

```
string sample = "First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line";
var extracted_strings = sample.Split('\n');
```

Please read more about [How to improve string concatenation performance in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/pl-pl/kb/306822)